# Wordpress $wp_query with CPT Distance and Featured Orderby

Tags: php, custom-post-type, wordpress

First time posting here; have spent the last few days on this and I am close but stuck. Using a poorly supported theme that works really well with all of our customizations. It is for a business directory website. The theme includes "Featured" placement to change the formatting and highlight an outputted listing. The theme also utilizes custom post types for the listings. Users enter a city, state and the theme returns as many listings as it can that fall within the search radius, we are trying to get any featured listings found within that radius to come to the top of results even if it is not the "closest". The theme sets the "distance" within a geo.php file using the following code:

```
static function posts_clauses( $clauses, $wp_query ) {
    extract(appthemes_geo_get_args());

    global $wpdb;

    $geo_query = $wp_query->get( 'app_geo_query' );

    if ( !$geo_query )
        return $clauses;

    extract( $geo_query, EXTR_SKIP );

    $R = 'mi' == $unit ? 3959 : 6371;

    $clauses['join'] .= $wpdb->prepare( " INNER JOIN (
        SELECT post_id, ( %d * acos( cos( radians(%f) ) * cos( radians(lat) ) * cos( radians(lng) - radians(%f) ) + sin( radians(%f) ) * sin( radians(lat) ) ) ) AS distance FROM $wpdb->app_geodata
    ) as distances ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = distances.post_id)
    ", $R, $lat, $lng, $lat );

    $clauses['where'] .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND distance < %f", (float) $rad );

    if ( 'distance' == $wp_query->get( 'orderby' ) ) {
        $clauses['orderby'] = 'distance ' . ( 'DESC' == strtoupper( $wp_query->get( 'order' ) ) ? 'DESC' : 'ASC' );
    }

    return $clauses;
}
```

}

Then within another file (views.php) there are parameters to change the sort order by highest rated, alphabetical, newest, etc. Where we are stuck is trying to get featured listings to come out on top of the distance results. There is a wp_query that does return featured at the top using the following code:

```
 function parse_query( $wp_query ) {
    global $va_options, $wpdb;

    $wp_query->set( 'ls', trim( get_query_var( 'ls' ) ) );
    $wp_query->set( 's', get_query_var( 'ls' ) );
    $wp_query->set( 'post_type', VA_LISTING_PTYPE );
    $wp_query->set( 'posts_per_page', $va_options->listings_per_page );

    if ( '' == $wp_query->get( 'order' ) )
        $wp_query->set( 'order', 'asc' );

    $orderby = $wp_query->get( 'orderby' );

    if ( empty( $orderby ) ) {
        $location = trim( $wp_query->get( 'location' ) );

        if ( !empty( $location ) ) {
            $orderby = $va_options->default_geo_search_sort;
        } else {
            $orderby = $va_options->default_search_sort;
        }

        $wp_query->set( 'orderby', $orderby );
    }

    $wp_query->set( 'va_orderby', $orderby );

    switch ( $orderby ) {
 case 'default':
        default:
            $wp_query->set( 'meta_key', VA_ITEM_FEATURED );
            $wp_query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
            $wp_query->set( 'order', 'desc' );
            $wp_query->set( 'va-featured', true );
            break;
    }
```

I have removed a few others "cases" to make the code easier to follow. Distance by default in the switch orderby looks like this:

```
            case 'distance':
            break;
```

This obviously is because the orderby is defined in the geo.php file. I have attempted adding $wp_query->set( 'meta_key', 'featured_cat'); (it is a number either 1 or 0 with 1 being Featured) and then adding an array for the orderby but it is not taking.

I think the answer is staring me in the face but am hoping for some help. Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. I commented out the the Orderby clause in the geo.php file

```
if ( 'distance' == $wp_query->get( 'orderby' ) ) {
    $clauses['orderby'] = 'distance ' . ( 'DESC' == strtoupper( $wp_query->get( 'order' ) ) ? 'DESC' : 'ASC' );
}
```

And moved the orderby rules into the views.php. With Wordpress 4.0 there is granular control ove rthe orderbys.